# Bungie Reach API - Realtime stats?

Tags: api, real-time, stat

I have been playing around with the  new bungie stat API that is available and have a question about it.

Is there any way I can get real time data, like matchmaking has just matched me with my team, is there anyway to get the names of my team mates?  Or are the stats restricted to basically the 'history', and not cataloged till after the match is over?

Thanks for your help,
-Will

Answer (score 0):

I'd say they would be history - to expensive to write it real time as people join and leave your lobby.

Plus it would be better to write it all at the end, not constantly throughout the game for performance reasons.